# dropdown_search with FutureBuilder but I don't know how to extract items data to populate it

Tags: json, flutter, sqlite, fullscreen

> i need help to populate a **dropdown_search** in flutter from a local database

```
        Future getList() async {
          final db = await getDatabase();
          final res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tb_point_of_Sale");

          List<PointOfSale> list =
          res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => PointOfSale.fromJson(c)).toList() : [];
          return list;
        }
```

I used **FutureBuilder** but I don't know how to extract **items** data... HELP PLEASE

> 

```
      FutureBuilder(
          future: PointOfSaleDao.db.getAll(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return DropdownSearch<String>(
                  mode: Mode.MENU,
                  showSearchBox: true,
                  showSelectedItem: true,
                  items: snapshot
                      .data[0].id, //PointOfSaleDao.db.getList(),
                  onChanged: print,
                  hint: "sélectionner",
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null) {
                      return "ce champ est obligatoire !";
                    }
                    return null;
                  });
            }
          },
        )
```